# How to automate consecutive bash command line writing for multiple files

Tags: python

Basically I need help for writing a script to repeat a command line times the number of elements from a list table, and every element value is used for replacing it three times in the main command line, besides every repeat is separated by **" && "** to form a consecutive string I can print out as text. I got a plain text file with 442 file names (without extension), let's say as a column without header, and every name or value I must replace it three times in the main command line, and repeat the command line replacing it with the next value times number of values: For instance

Here's the main command line I want to repeate using file or value **SL5Y** and print out

prokka --prefix **SL5Y** --cpus 6 --outdir **SL5Y** --rfam --addgenes --addmrna --cdsrnaolap **SL5Y**.fna

And here's the table

SL5Y

SL6Y

SO5Y

So what I basically need is a consecutive command line that looks as follows, but for 442 files, replacing every table value three times inside the repeat corresponding to that value; separated by **' && '**

prokka --prefix **SL5Y** --cpus 6 --outdir **SL5Y** --rfam --addgenes --addmrna --cdsrnaolap **SL5Y**.fna **&&** prokka --prefix **SL6Y** --cpus 6 --outdir **SL6Y** --rfam --addgenes --addmrna --cdsrnaolap **SL6Y**.fna **&&** prokka --prefix **SO5Y** --cpus 6 --outdir **SO5Y** --rfam --addgenes --addmrna --cdsrnaolap **SO5Y**.fna

Comment: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71476498/4653379) asked a few days ago, with no response to comments for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use Python to do what you are trying to do, assuming the file names (without extensions) are contained in a file named `'list_of_file_names_without_extension.txt'`:

```py
file = open('list_of_file_names_without_extension.txt')
fileNames = [x.strip('\n') for x in file.readlines()]
'''
# Should look something like this, but with arbitrary number of elements (442 according to question):
fileNames = [
    'SL5Y', 'SL6Y', 'SO5Y'
]
'''
print(fileNames)
commandList = [f'prokka --prefix {f} --cpus 6 --outdir {f} --rfam --addgenes --addmrna --cdsrnaolap {f}.fna' for f in fileNames]
command = ' && '.join(commandList)
print(command)
```

Output:

```
prokka --prefix SL5Y --cpus 6 --outdir SL5Y --rfam --addgenes --addmrna --cdsrnaolap SL5Y.fna && prokka --prefix SL6Y --cpus 6 --outdir SL6Y --rfam --addgenes --addmrna --cdsrnaolap SL6Y.fna && prokka --prefix SO5Y --cpus 6 --outdir SO5Y --rfam --addgenes --addmrna --cdsrnaolap SO5Y.fna
```